# What is this forward-looking Déjà Vu-like phenomenon?

Tags: memory, terminology

In the past I've always thought deja vu was a feeling of having done something before because you actually had done something quite like it before and the current environment is bringing that to mind but in the past few years, maybe longer, I've had a different deja vu-like case: It's a feeling at one point in time, that feels like deja vu, except that I particularly feel/know it *hasn't* happened before, which then, at a later time, actually comes about happening in the same place as I had thought about it earlier. In both the first and second events I am particularly aware of what I'm feeling as it has happened a few times. It doesn't feel like a trick of the mind like my explanation for regular deja vu would have me believe.

Is this a known or common deja vu-like phenomenon? Is there anything that would explain it like my explanation of regular deja vu?

Comment: This isn't a self-help question. It's a question about what cognitive phenomenon the description might be referring to.